# Is this mapping between C++ class member cardinality and declaration OK?

Tags: c++, composition

I have three kinds of cardinality for class(structure) members in my design.

- 0 or 1
- 0 or more
- exactly one

I have mapped them to following declaration as class(structure) members

```cpp
class Foo {
        ExactlyOnce exactlyOnce;
        std::unique_ptr<ZeroOrOnce> zeroOrOnce;
        std::list<std::shared_ptr<ZeroOrMore>> zeroOrMore;
};
```

I'm planning to generalize this pattern throughout the whole package, is this approach OK or it has some bugs w.r.t. member cardinality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fine.

Consider the following though:

- using `boost::optional` for `ZeroOrOne` (if you already use boost); the intent behind it is more explicit as the API is optimized for this.
- using `std::vector<T>` instead of `std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>` for `ZeroOrMore`. Outside of the case when you have large/expensive objects and perform front and random insertions, a vector tends to be more efficient.

Comment: Agreed on both, particularly `vector`. N.B. - `optional` is being integrated as `std::optional` in C++17

Answer (score 2):

For `zeroOrMore` cardinality store the elements by value, not by pointer. Store pointers only as a last resort, if nothing else would do.

Comment: Wouldn't that be slow if I don't have move constructors?

Comment: @Samik zero or more by value could require an optional type. But the point about pointers is a very good one. Also, the ownership semantics are a separate issue to cardinality. Why would you use shared ownership for zero or more, but unique ownership for one or more?

Comment: @Samik It depends, use your best judgement and verify it with a profiler. Also, elements do not move in `std::list`, whereas they do in `std::vector`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I thought `Foo` is owning `ZeroOrOnce` and sharing `ZeroOrMore` with `std::list`?

Comment: @Samik `Foo` owns the container and therefore the smart pointers. They can often be `unique_ptr` and if so, should be. Try it and see! (Remember to iterate by reference, etc.)